# Show several Json link on a tab

Tags: json, url, tabs, ionic3, show

I m trying to link several Json link on unique page and diplay for each Json the specific content on a tab.

For example:

home.ts

```
  getAmericaData(){
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(the link url json from America Music review);
    data.subscribe(data =>{
      this.reviews = data["Collections"].Review;
    });
  }

  getFranceData(){
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(the link url json from France Music review);
    data.subscribe(data =>{
      this.reviews = data["Collections"].Review;
    });
  }
```

home.html ( this is for the tab America )

```
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'reviews'">
            <ion-card *ngFor="let review of reviews; let i=index;" [hidden]="i>11" (click)="showDetails(review)">
                <ion-list>
                    <h3 *ngIf="!reviews.length">No Search Found</h3>
                    <ion-item>
                        <div class="my-content line-break">
                            <h2>{{review?.Title}}</h2>
                            <p>{{review?.ShortStory}}</p>
                            <button ion-button color="Yellow" item-end full>More</button>
                        </div>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-list>
```

As you can see, i did for the  America Json link and it works perfectly but now how should i do for the tab France ?

Thanks !

Comment: nevermind i'm just stupid ... 

if someone as the same issue dont forget this guys  *ngIf="  ...